# Old, unpasteurized orange juice has extra tang

Tags: juice, acidity, oranges

I've been buying unpasteurized orange juice recently for its richer flavor, as compared to pasteurized OJ.  I've had some sitting in the fridge for about a week, and upon tasting it just now I noticed an *extra* tang that I'm pretty sure was not there when I first bought it.  I presume this is due to some new acid in the juice that has formed from the breakdown of other components of the juice as it aged.  I quite like this additional complexity of the flavor, but I am curious: What is it?  In particular, what acid might I be tasting?

Comment: Could it be alcohol?

Comment: I had this happen just this week to unpasteurized OJ. We did not smell anything off, nor taste any bad or even alcoholic, but it tasted slightly carbonated to me. I vote CO2. From some kind of organism.

Answer (score 3):

It is almost certainly a fermentation - opened juice does not keep for a week in the fridge. So you got some bacteria in it which are creating tangy byproducts (lactic or acetic acid). It is a method of creating fermented drinks such as cider (or even fruit wine), but without following a tested process, you cannot be sure if some of the bacteria may be harmful. So it is not safe by today's standards.

Comment: So do you think it's fermenting and will turn to Alcohol I've had old juice go bad on me and other juice I drank knowing it was old but never got drunk .I'm single so I buy in smaller quantity now .

Comment: Fermentation does not automatically mean alcohol (sauerkraut is not alcoholic, for example) and when it does, it creates alcohol slowly. If yours was an alcoholic fermentation, you probably had 0.5% or less alcohol in the juice, you would have needed to drink 3.5 liters to feel the same effect as from one small beer.

Answer (score 1):

I just opened a jug of unpasteurized orange juice that had been sitting in my fridge for a couple of weeks (as long as I've ever let it sit) and got a huge wallop of what I'm pretty sure is vinegar.  So I believe the acid in question is acetic acid.

Answer (score 0):

> What is it? In particular, what acid might I be tasting?

Could be all kinds of stuff. In any event, you can be almost certain that a changing flavor of unpasteurized OJ is due to something not very healthy. [Example literature](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=unpasteurized%20orange%20juice).

If you really like the acidic flavors, consider purchasing pasteurized OJ, and then adding *Tart Cherry Juice Concentrate*. Or even *food grade citric acid*, a common ingredient in Sherbets.